# column ambiguously defined sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run this in sql plus but it is giving me this error

```
 SELECT reviewer_address, reviewer_name, review_date
FROM reviewers, reviews
INNER JOIN reviews ON reviewers.reviewer_address = reviews.review_date
INNER JOIN reviewers ON reviews.review_date = reviewers_address;

 ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

These are the tables of reviews and reviewers

```
CREATE TABLE reviewers  (
    reviewer_id         NUMBER (6),
    reviewer_name       VARCHAR2 (30),
    review_name         VARCHAR2 (15), 
    reviewer_address    REF address_type SCOPE IS addresses
);

CREATE TABLE reviews    (
    review_id           NUMBER (6),
    review_name         VARCHAR2 (30),
    review_date         DATE,
    reviewer_id         NUMBER (6) NOT NULL,
    venue_id            NUMBER (6) NOT NULL
);
```

And these are the inserts for them two tables

```
--reviews
INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review_name, review_date, reviewer_id, venue_id)
VALUES (1, 'MIKE POWELL', '03-DEC-2015', 1, 1);

INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review_name, review_date, reviewer_id, venue_id)
VALUES (2, 'JOHN MAYER', '15-MAY-2004', 2, 2);

INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review_name, review_date, reviewer_id, venue_id)
VALUES (3, 'SETH CONNOR', '25-JAN-2011', 3, 3);

INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review_name, review_date, reviewer_id, venue_id)
VALUES (4, 'JULIA SMITH', '08-AUG-2013', 4, 4);

INSERT INTO reviews (review_id, review_name, review_date, reviewer_id, venue_id)
VALUES (5, 'MADONNA MARLEY', '30-NOV-2001', 5, 5);


--reviewers
INSERT INTO reviewers (reviewer_id, reviewer_name, review_name, reviewer_address)
SELECT 1, 'MIKE POWELL', 'TEST REVIEW', REF(a)
FROM addresses a
WHERE street = '13 JAMES ROAD';

INSERT INTO reviewers (reviewer_id, reviewer_name, review_name, reviewer_address)
SELECT 2, 'JOHN MAYER', 'MAIN REVIEW', REF(a)
FROM addresses a
WHERE street = '54 BRIDGE STREET';

INSERT INTO reviewers (reviewer_id, reviewer_name, review_name, reviewer_address)
SELECT 3, 'SETH CONNOR', 'CAR REVIEW', REF(a)
FROM addresses a
WHERE street = '10 LIME STREET';

INSERT INTO reviewers (reviewer_id, reviewer_name, review_name, reviewer_address)
SELECT 4, 'JULIA SMITH', 'BEAUTY REVIEW', REF(a)
FROM addresses a 
WHERE street = '1 PALL MALL STREET';

INSERT INTO reviewers (reviewer_id, reviewer_name, review_name, reviewer_address)
SELECT 5, 'MADONNA MARLEY', 'CLOTHES REVIEW', REF(a)
FROM addresses a
WHERE street = '28 MAIN ROAD';
```

I hope this makes it easier for you guys

Comment: You know you select from each table twice?

Comment: Never mix old, implicit join syntax with modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Are you really comparing an address from one table with a date from another table? Or is that an error (perhaps from editing)?

Answer (score 1):

Never mix old, implicit join syntax with modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. 
And don't duplicate the tables in the select list.

```
SELECT reviewer_address, reviewer_name, review_date
FROM reviewers
INNER JOIN reviews ON reviewers.reviewer_id = reviews.reviewer_id
```

Comment: ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE 

I have changed some bits on it just to try out which will work better and the new code is this

Comment: SELECT rs.reviewer_address, rs.reviewer_name, r.review_id
FROM reviewers rs
INNER JOIN reviews r
ON rs.reviewer_address = r.review_id;

Comment: but the error is now this ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF got NUMBER

Comment: Edit your question, add table definitions and some sample table data. So we don't have to guess how to join!

Comment: Done ! i hope that helps

Comment: Great, try my adjusted query!

Answer (score 0):

Please use either :

```
SELECT reviewer_address, reviewer_name, review_date
FROM reviewers, reviews
where reviewers.reviewer_address = reviews.review_date
```

or this

```
SELECT reviewer_address, reviewer_name, review_date
FROM reviewers
INNER JOIN reviews ON reviewers.reviewer_address = reviews.review_date
```

Comment: if use that and run the file on sql plus it states this error

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE